# illegal string offset foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

HI Following is the code , i am trying to print the array which contain values of drop down menu
and then 2nd foreach loop is trying to selected the field.
The output  is the way i want , mean it print the all menu item, and the selected one,

```
foreach($results as $data): 
        $st = '';
        foreach($SelectedActor as $SelectedActor):
        if($SelectedActor['id']==$data['id']){$st='selected="selected"';}
         endforeach;
        $dd .="<option ".$st."  value=".$data['id']."> ".$data['artist_name']."    </option>";

        endforeach;
```

but the page also show this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'id'

Filename: controllers/replik.php

Line Number: 328
```

Vardump  for these two array are

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'artist_name' => string ' oyuncu' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'artist_name' => string 'hep brabir' (length=10)

array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'artist_name' => string 'oyuncu' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      'artist_name' => string 'hep brabir' (length=10)
```

Can any one help me to get the reason of this error.

Comment: `var_dump($SelectedActor, $data)` - one of these is not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 foreach($SelectedActor as $SelectedActor):
        if($SelectedActor['id']==$data['id']){$st='selected="selected"';}
```

here you use the same name of `$SelectedActor`, maybe

```
foreach($SelectedActor as $ItemSelectedActor):
            if($ItemSelectedActor['id']==$data['id']){$st='selected="selected"';}
```

is ok

Comment: Sorry for the stupid mistake  i make here.
I was doing 

    foreach($SelectedActor as $SelectedActor):

i do it like 

  

     foreach($SelectedActor as $SelectedActores):

just changes the second  variable name and it work.

Comment: but i dont unsdertand in this case why it gives error. mostly when  do foreachloop way it work fines, in this case there were two foreach loop so its errror ? or thier is ome other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Below line is wrong:

```
foreach($SelectedActor as $SelectedActor)
```

You need to do:

```
foreach($SelectedActor as $actor):
    if($actor['id']==$data['id']){
        $st='selected="selected"';
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: You might want to consider fixing this line `if($actor'id']==$data['id']){`